# What's wrong with this regular expression finding specific letters?

Tags: regex

I'd like to find result that includes all the letters, number, underscore, hyphen, **special characters**, space...(every possible character) between specific letters. So I come up with this

```
/^(specific)[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]{1,20}(letters)$/
```

expected result:
specific asf124AD_-G letters

Which I got "Invalid req expressions. Invalid character class".

I searched on google, but still not sure what to fix. 
Any comment will be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: The `-` needs to be at the end of the character class i.e. `[[a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your error is "_-\s", interpeted as any char between
"_" and any white character.

The problem is that "-" between brackets means a **range** of chars between
the preceding and following char, but both these chars must be **single**
chars, not e.g. "\s" meaning *any white char*.

The above rule does not apply when "-" is:

- first / last char between brackets,
- quoted, e.g. with a "\",

so to correct your regex move this minus e.g. to the last position, just before
the closing "]".

Another remark is that there is little sense to use a capturing groups
to capture a **fixed** text.

Such fixed text (to match) should be left alone and **other** text
should be put in a capturing group (or groups).

So I think you should use rather the following regex:

```
^specific([\w\s-]{1,20})letters$
```

Details:

- `^specific` - start of string and *specific*,
- `(` - start of a capturing group containing:

  - `[\w\s-]` - any of: word char (letter, digit and "_"),
    white char (space, Tab, NewLine) or minus,
  - `{1,20}` - repetition count,
- `)` - end of the capturing group,
- `letters$` - *letters* and end of string.

For a working example see: https://regex101.com/r/MHLubC/1

To capture "other" chars mentioned in your comment, add them **before**
the "-", so that it keeps its last position between brackets.

So the whole regex is now:

```
^specific([\w\s\\~!@#$%^&*()+=?-]{1,20})letters$
```

Note that between brackets none of these chars needs to be quoted, even
anchor chars and parentheses.

But if you want to try all of them, adding them to your initial source
string, you should change the upper limit of repetition count to some
bigger value. Otherwise the sequence of chars to match will be too long
and will not be matched solely for this reason.

Note also that *$* terminating the whole regex is the **anchor** (matching
the end of source string), not the litteral *$* itself.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer : )
Btw, that reg Exp. doesn't get the result with '$'..  Is there way to capturing all the special characters(~!@#$%^&*()+=)??